# Removing old files from home directories

Tags: linux, bash, find, md5

I need to find and remove files older than 2 weeks from the home directories of my cluster.
I do not want to let people just "touch" the file to change the modification date and keep it for another 2 weeks. (I'm talking about files of several hundreds of Gb)
I thought about doing md5 check on the content and comparing it against a list with the file creation date, but maybe there is an easier solution.

Comment: You might be able to check creation date, but that does not show anything about modifications.

Comment: Since linux does not keep track of the creation time, you might want to look for something like this :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/470134/how-do-i-find-the-creation-time-of-a-file

Comment: @David, this can be very dangerous. You will remove (by your definition) users `.bashrc` files, ssh keys and so on. So add additional checks!

Comment: Is the purpose of the deletion space savings, or something else?  You can set quotas and let users work within those limits.

Comment: @RomeoNinov do not worry, I would exclude certain directories :)

Comment: @JohnMahowald I cannot. Users need to work with huge files, I must allow them to do so, but they have to delete them in reasonable times.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove files from the home directories with the following command :

```
find /home/*/ -mtime +15 -type f -delete
```

And easily put it in a cron to do it automatically.

Comment: Was thinking the same, but then I read the whole question about users using `touch`

Comment: Exactly, this won't work for me :/